# Excel: Create columns based on information in data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For reference, I am pulling data from patient's charts into Excel, and the list of diagnosis are contained within one cell. I know how to separate them into different columns, but I need every diagnosis contained in that data set to be labeled along the top row, and for each patient in the following rows it would display either a '1' or a '0' contingent on whether or not this diagnosis is contained.

Something like;

| Name | Adjustment Disorder | ADHD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 1 |
| Mary | 1 | 1 |

Thank you!

Comment: would you clarify what is your input and the expected output? Thanks

Comment: Output above - however you have been exceptionally vague RE: input mate.  It's like you do not mention/allude to anything RE: patient names, what to match against RE: their respective conditions (are multiple conditions possible - this would influence the precise nature of functions in question considerably) from the perspective as to things like: are patient names also included in a single cell? No hard-feelings, but you've given us more information but areas that you do not need addressing (things you are able to do), and nothing/very little on things you are aren't (which should be the only

Comment: thing you describe in particular / explict detail with screenshots if necessary/there is any slight confiusion.. nope - gotto downvote this Q and ignore / come back when you have given adequate info because this is a time-blocker for me already. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the diagnoses are in column B, and that what we are seeing as output is in columns D:F, put the following into cell E2 and drag the fill handle over and down: =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$1,$B2))/1